# Variable de sesion funciona en local pero no en web

Tags: php, sesiones

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo que al ejecutarlo en el local funciona pero en el servidor web no. La variable de sesion llamada DETALLE esta vacia y deberia cargarse al seleccionar un comprobante. Pero no se carga.
En el archivo congif abro la sesion con session_start()
Revise la configuracion de php y ambos (local y web) tienen la misma version y tambien la misma configuracion. Lo que no pude saber como ver en hostinger (donde esta alojado) son los permisos de escritura.

Archivo estado_cuenta:

```
<?php

require 'config/config.php';
require 'header.php';
require 'detalle.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['cuenta'])) {
    header("Location: ov.php");
}

?>

<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-xl-12">
        <h3 class="text-muted">Estado de Cuenta</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mb-4">
    <p class="text-muted">
        <small>(Los pagos realizados en Entidades Externas y/o en linea, se verán reflejados en las próximas 24/48 hs)</small>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <?php
        $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM deudas WHERE cuenta=:usuario ORDER BY periodo DESC");
        $sql->execute(['usuario' => $usuario]);
        $resultado = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        ?>
        <div class="col-lg-8 mb-4">
            <br>



            <table class="table" style="text-align: center;" id="tbl-buys">
                <thead class="table-secondary">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Servicio</th>
                        <th scope="col">Período</th>
                        <th scope="col">Vencimiento</th>
                        <th scope="col">Importe</th>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="checkboxes">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($resultado as $rowdeuda) {
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $rowdeuda['servicio']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rowdeuda['periodo']; ?></td>
                            <td><strong><?php echo $rowdeuda['vencimiento']; ?></strong></td>
                            <td>$ <?php echo $rowdeuda['importe']; ?></td>
                            <form action="" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($rowdeuda['id'], COD, KEY);  ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="servicio" id="servicio" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($rowdeuda['servicio'], COD, KEY);  ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="periodo" id="periodo" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($rowdeuda['periodo'], COD, KEY); ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="vencimiento" id="vencimiento" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($rowdeuda['vencimiento'], COD, KEY); ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="importe" id="importe" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($rowdeuda['importe'], COD, KEY); ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="comprobante" id="comprobante" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($rowdeuda['comprobante'], COD, KEY); ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="referencia" id="referencia" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($rowdeuda['referencia'], COD, KEY); ?>">
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" name="btnAccion" value="Pagar" type="submit">
                                        <i class="bi bi-app"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </form>

                        </tr>
                </tbody>
            <?php } ?>
            </table>
            <?php if (empty($rowdeuda)) { ?>
                <h4 class="text-muted my-4">No adeuda servicios</h4>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="text-secondary-emphasis bg-secondary-subtle border border-secondary-subtle rounded-3 d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <a href="detalle_view.php" class="btn color p-3"><span class="fs-5">PAGAR (<?php echo (empty($_SESSION['DETALLE'])) ? 0 : count($_SESSION['DETALLE']); ?>)</span></a>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</main>

<?php
require 'footer.php';
?>
```

Archivo detalle:

```
<?php
$mensaje = "";

if (isset($_POST['btnAccion'])) {

    switch ($_POST['btnAccion']) {

        case 'Pagar':

            if (is_numeric(openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'], COD, KEY))) {
                $ID = openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'], COD, KEY);
                $mensaje .= "Ok ID correcto " . $ID;
            } else {
                $mensaje = "Ups... ID incorrecto " . $ID;
            }
            if (is_string(openssl_decrypt($_POST['servicio'], COD, KEY))) {
                $SERVICIO = openssl_decrypt($_POST['servicio'], COD, KEY);
                $mensaje .= "Ok servicio correcto " . $SERVICIO . "<br>";
            } else {
                $mensaje .= "Ups... servicio incorrecto ";
                break;
            }
            if (is_string(openssl_decrypt($_POST['periodo'], COD, KEY))) {
                $PERIODO = openssl_decrypt($_POST['periodo'], COD, KEY);
                $mensaje .= "Ok periodo correcto " . $PERIODO . "<br>";
            } else {
                $mensaje .= "Ups... periodo incorrecto ";
                break;
            }
            if (is_string(openssl_decrypt($_POST['vencimiento'], COD, KEY))) {
                $VENCIMIENTO = openssl_decrypt($_POST['vencimiento'], COD, KEY);
                $mensaje .= "Ok vencimiento correcto " . $VENCIMIENTO . "<br>";
            } else {
                $mensaje .= "Ups... vencimiento incorrecto ";
                break;
            }
            if (is_numeric(openssl_decrypt($_POST['importe'], COD, KEY))) {
                $IMPORTE = openssl_decrypt($_POST['importe'], COD, KEY);
                $mensaje .= "Ok importe correcto " . $IMPORTE;
            } else {
                $mensaje .= "Ups... importe incorrecto ";
                break;
            }
            if (is_string(openssl_decrypt($_POST['comprobante'], COD, KEY))) {
                $COMPROBANTE = openssl_decrypt($_POST['comprobante'], COD, KEY);
                $mensaje .= "Ok comprobante correcto " . $COMPROBANTE;
            } else {
                $mensaje .= "Ups... comprobante incorrecto ";
                break;
            }
            if (is_numeric(openssl_decrypt($_POST['referencia'], COD, KEY))) {
                $REFERENCIA = openssl_decrypt($_POST['referencia'], COD, KEY);
                $mensaje .= "Ok referencia correcto " . $REFERENCIA;
            } else {
                $mensaje .= "Ups... referencia incorrecto ";
                break;
            }
            if (!isset($_SESSION['DETALLE'])) {
                $deuda = array(
                    'ID' => $ID,
                    'SERVICIO' => $SERVICIO,
                    'PERIODO' => $PERIODO,
                    'VENCIMIENTO' => $VENCIMIENTO,
                    'IMPORTE' => $IMPORTE,
                    'COMPROBANTE' => $COMPROBANTE,
                    'REFERENCIA' => $REFERENCIA
                );
                $_SESSION['DETALLE'][0] = $deuda;
                $mensaje = "Comprobante agregado";
            } else {
                $idDeuda = array_column($_SESSION['DETALLE'], "ID");
                if (in_array($ID, $idDeuda)) {
                    echo "<script>alert('Comprobante ya seleccionado')</script>";
                    $mensaje = "";
                } else {
                    $numeroDeudas = count($_SESSION['DETALLE']);
                    $deuda = array(
                        'ID' => $ID,
                        'SERVICIO' => $SERVICIO,
                        'PERIODO' => $PERIODO,
                        'VENCIMIENTO' => $VENCIMIENTO,
                        'IMPORTE' => $IMPORTE,
                        'COMPROBANTE' => $COMPROBANTE,
                        'REFERENCIA' => $REFERENCIA
                    );
                    $_SESSION['DETALLE'][$numeroDeudas] = $deuda;
                    $mensaje = "Comprobante agregado";
                }
            }
            //$mensaje = print_r($_SESSION, true);
            break;

        case "Eliminar":
            if (is_numeric(openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'], COD, KEY))) {
                $ID = openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'], COD, KEY);

                foreach ($_SESSION['DETALLE'] as $indice => $deuda) {
                    if ($deuda['ID'] == $ID) {
                        unset($_SESSION['DETALLE'][$indice]);
                        $_SESSION['DETALLE'] = array_values($_SESSION["DETALLE"]);
                        //echo "<script>alert('comprobante borrado...')</script>";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $mensaje = "Ups... ID incorrecto " . $ID;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Archivo detalle_view

```
<?php
require 'config/config.php';
require 'header.php';
require 'detalle.php';

?>
<br>

<h3>Detalle de comprobantes a pagar</h3>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12 my-5">
            <?php if (!empty($_SESSION['DETALLE'])) { ?>
                <table class="table table-light table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="15%">Servicio</th>
                            <th width="15%">Comprobante</th>
                            <th width="10% text-center">Período</th>
                            <th width="15% text-center">Vencimiento</th>
                            <th width="20% text-center">N° de Ref. Interno</th>
                            <th width="15% text-center">Importe</th>
                            <th width="10%"></th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php $total = 0; ?>
                        <?php foreach ($_SESSION['DETALLE'] as $indice => $deuda) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $deuda['SERVICIO']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $deuda['COMPROBANTE']; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $deuda['PERIODO']; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $deuda['VENCIMIENTO']; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $deuda['REFERENCIA']; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center">$ <?php echo  number_format($deuda['IMPORTE'], 2, ',', '.'); ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <form action="" method="POST">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($deuda['ID'], COD, KEY);  ?>">
                                        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit" name="btnAccion" value="Eliminar"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php $total = $total + $deuda['IMPORTE']; ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5" align="right">
                                <h3>Total</h3>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                <h3>$<?php echo number_format($total, 2, ',', '.'); ?></h3>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <form method="POST" action="pagar.php">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-block btn-lg color my-5 d-flex float-end">Procesar Pago >></button>
                </form>

            <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    No ha seleccionado ningún comprobante
                </div>
                <a href="estado_cuenta.php" class="btn btn-success text-center">Volver</a>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Has revisado el log de errores?

Comment: Si, lo he revisado

Comment: ¿No aparece allí ningún error reciente?

Comment: No no, ningun error

Comment: Si el log de errores no dice nada (¿seguro que estás revisando en el lugar correcto?), será complicado depurar tu código, a no ser que incluyas un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable en el que podamos revisar qué ocurre con las variables de sesión.